# Javascript Element Validation within If-Statement

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm having issues when adding an element validation within an if-statement.

Basically, irrelevant of the result of the if-statement, Protractor is still trying to find the element specified within the if-statement.

Here is the code that is still running even though the if-statement returned false:

```
if (thisIsAlwaysFalse == true) {
    console.log(':::::::::::::::' + thisIsAlwaysFalse);
    it('If-statement test', function(done) {
        var elementToFind = element(by.xpath('//td[contains(@class,"hello")]'));
        browser.wait(function() {
            return browser.isElementPresent(elementToFind);
        }, 5000);
        elementToFind.click();
        done();
    });
}
```

Also, funny thing is that the console.log part is successfully ignored!

Anyone has a solution for this or possibly knows why this is happening?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Change the '//td[contains(@class,"hello")]' part to other arbitrary thing to check whether it is caused by other part of the code.

Comment: you don't need the `== true` in `if (thisIsAlwaysFalse == true)`  you can simply write `if (thisIsAlwaysFalse)` the `== true` is an extra thing. The code under it won't run if the variable is a falsy value regardless of what it is named, and will only run if it is true.

Comment: Have you logged out the variable before the `if` to ensure it is actually false?

Comment: How the `thisIsAlwaysFalse` is defined? It is probably a **promise** that returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you debugged the problematic area?
Nevertheless, your always-false statement is probably a [promise](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises), which is always a truthy value. In order to solve it, you need to put the whole block to then callback.
For example:

```
doStuff()
.then(function (result) {
    if (yourAlwatsFalsyCondition(result) {
        return elementFindYouDid(results)
            .moreStuff(doMore);
    }
})
```